# How to Get a List of Direct Dependencies on a Makefile Target

Tags: shell, makefile

I am working on a project which has a little complicated Makefile.

It has a lot of function calls and string substitutes to get the list of objects and phony targets.

I am trying to get the direct dependency on an target, e.g.

```
FOO_VAR := abc def ghi

test: \
foo \
bar \
$(FOO_VAR) \
whatever
```

I should get

```
foo
bar
abc
def
ghi
whatever
```

Even if these targets have further dependencies.

I have followed

[List goals/targets in GNU make that contain variables in their definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063507/list-goals-targets-in-gnu-make)

to use `make -qp | awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}'`

However it will return all the targets, not just direct dependencies.

Comment: You want the direct prerequisites of a single target or its entire prerequisite chain (that is the prereqs of its prereqs, etc.)?

Comment: Just direct prerequisites of a single target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `make -qp | grep 'target:'` do what you want?

Or possibly `make -qp | grep 'target.*:'` (in case it isn't the only/last target on that line)?

Also see [Eric Melski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7390874/258523)'s answer for a more efficient (but longer and requires small prep-work) command to run for the make bit of that pipeline.